# Function execution took 60015 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

This code is a Google cloud function node.js script that exports a function fsdb_sch which uses the node-schedule and firebase-admin. The script sets up a scheduled job that runs every day at midnight using the node-schedule module. The job reads values from a Firebase Realtime Database at the location All_machines/Generator using firebase-admin module, and then writes the same values to new locations within the same database.

The Firebase Realtime Database is accessed with the help of a service account which is stored in a JSON file, ./******************************-7878b7ca66.json.

But When I am running this code I am getting only this error in logs nothing else this error `Function execution took 60015 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'`. I have increase the time till 540s but function stop after 540s i have also increase the memory but nothing work.  But the same code is running fine in my local system from pas few days without any errors.
this is my code :

```js
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

const Admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { getDatabase } = require("firebase-admin/database");
const serviceAccount = require("./*********************************-7878b7ca66.json");
Admin.initializeApp({
  credential: Admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://****************************.firebasedatabase.app"
});

exports.fsdb_sch = (req, res) => {
  const db = Admin.database();
const Db = getDatabase();
const ref = Db.ref("All_machines/Generator");
const Ref = db.ref("All_machines/Generator")
    

schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 * * *',() => {
ref.once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((data) => {
    ref.child(data.key).child('waterY').once('value', (snapshot) => {
        let childref = Ref.child(data.key).child('waterYY');
        childref.set(snapshot.val());
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        });
      ref.child(data.key).child('waterT').once('value', (snapshot) => {
        let childref = Ref.child(data.key).child('waterY');
        childref.set(snapshot.val());
        console.log(snapshot.val());
      });
      ref.child(data.key).child('compY').once('value', (snapshot) => {
        let childref = Ref.child(data.key).child('compYY');
        childref.set(snapshot.val());
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        });
      ref.child(data.key).child('compT').once('value', (snapshot) => {
        let childref = Ref.child(data.key).child('compY');
        childref.set(snapshot.val());
        console.log(snapshot.val());
      });
      });
  }, (errorObject) => {
    console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.name);
  });
});
};
```

This is Package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": "Cloud Function for Schedular",
   "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
      "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
      "start": "npm run shell",
      "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
      "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.4.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
    "mqtt": "^4.3.7",
    "node-schedule": "^2.1.0"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
 
}
```

And this is the folder structure
[image]

Logs:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cloud functions have [timeout](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/timeout), you should not use cloud functions for long running tasks.

You can use [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub) to trigger your function using cloud scheduler instead.

1. scheduler will publish to a topic(just empty data) based on your cron expression
2. topic will trigger your cloud function, and execute required script.